# How do I use underscore.js in angular 9 project

Tags: underscore.js

1. Added the package using ***npm install underscore***
2. in angular.json added

```js
"scripts": [
              "node_modules/underscore/underscore.js"
            ]
```

3. In app.component.ts added following lines.

```js
import { underscore } from 'underscore';
declare var _:any;
let groupedArrayByStartTime = _.groupBy(
            inputWordsArray,
            'start'
          );
```

when I run the code, error is: **ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'groupBy' of undefined**

What am I doing wrong here. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Found my mistake. in step

```js
declare var _: any;
```

to

```js
declare var _: underscore;
```